# Python maths does not multiply, it uses string instead?

Tags: python, python-2.7, math

I was just testing a little python maths and I could not multiply numbers! I am really confused because I thought this simple code would work:

```
test = raw_input("answer")
new = test * 5
print new
```

Instead, it just gave whatever I wrote five times next to each other. E.g I write 8 and it prints 88888! Can somebody explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast to `int`, `raw_input` returns a string:

```
test = int(raw_input("answer"))
```

You can see the `type` is `str` without casting:

```
In [5]: test = raw_input("answer ")
answer 8    
In [6]: type(test)
Out[6]: str
In [7]: test = int(raw_input("answer "))
answer 8    
In [8]: type(test)
Out[8]: int
```

When you multiply the string python will return the string repeated `test` times.

Comment: Yeah, just: `test = int(raw_input("answer"))` (first line) or `new = int(test) * 5` (second line). I like the former better in terms of readability.